# Trying to mailmerge from FirebirdDB into Word but unable to open the data source

Tags: c#, ms-word, connection-string, firebird, mailmerge

I'm trying to mailmerge data from a firebird database into a word document. I have a single table "USERS" with the fields, "NAME", "ADDRESS1" and "CITY".

However I can't get word to open the data source. The line below,

```
        wrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(myConnection1.Database, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oQuery, ref oMissing, ref oFalse, ref oMissing);
```

Is throwing: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ProtoLAS.exe

Additional information: Word was unable to open the data source.

I feel like I've tried everything. Below you can find the complete form code.

```
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
namespace ProtoLAS
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString =
            "User=SYSDBA;" +
            "Password=masterkey;" +
            "Database=E:\\data\\LAS.FDB;" +
            "DataSource=localhost;" +
            "Port=3050;" +
            "Dialect=3;" +
            "Charset=NONE;" +
            "Role=;" +
            "Connection lifetime=15;" +
            "Pooling=true;" +
            "MinPoolSize=0;" +
            "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
            "Packet Size=8192;" +
            "ServerType=0";
        FbConnection myConnection1 = new FbConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            // Open connection.
            myConnection1.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Word.Application wrdApp;
        Word._Document wrdDoc;
        Object oTemplate = "E:\\Template.docx";
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Object oFalse = false;
        Object oTrue = true;
        Word.MailMerge wrdMailMerge;

        // Create an instance of Word  and make it visible.
        wrdApp = new Word.Application();
        wrdApp.Visible = true;

        // Create MailMerge Data.                        
        wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        wrdDoc.Select();
        wrdMailMerge = wrdDoc.MailMerge;
        object oQuery = "SELECT NAME,ADDRESS1,CITY from USERS";
        wrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(myConnection1.Database, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oQuery, ref oMissing, ref oFalse, ref oMissing);
        wrdMailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = true;

        // Perform mail merge.
        wrdMailMerge.Destination = Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
        wrdMailMerge.Execute(ref oFalse);

        // Close the Template document.
        wrdDoc.Saved = true;
        wrdDoc.Close(ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        // Release References.            
        wrdMailMerge = null;
        wrdDoc = null;
        wrdApp = null;
        myConnection1.Close();
    }
```

Why won't Word open the data source?

Edit: Stacktrace

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2146822366
  HResult=-2146822366
  HelpLink=wdmain11.chm#25402
  Message=Word was unable to open the data source.
  Source=Microsoft Word
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(String Name, Object& Format, Object& ConfirmConversions, Object& ReadOnly, Object& LinkToSource, Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object& PasswordDocument, Object& PasswordTemplate, Object& Revert, Object& WritePasswordDocument, Object& WritePasswordTemplate, Object& Connection, Object& SQLStatement, Object& SQLStatement1, Object& OpenExclusive, Object& SubType)
       at ProtoLAS.Main.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\nathan\Source\Repos\PrototypeLAS\ProtoLAS\ProtoLAS\Main.cs:line 64
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ProtoLAS.Program.Main() in C:\Users\nathan\Source\Repos\PrototypeLAS\ProtoLAS\ProtoLAS\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Remove the `Role=;` from the connection string (I've seen problems in other drivers when specifying an empty role instead of **no** role). If that doesn't fix it, then please post the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Remove role, still getting the same. Stacktrace added to post.

Answer (score -2):

If you can afford spending some money on 3rd party products, I would recommend two products that would make your life much easier:

1. LLBLGen Pro is an ORM tool for creating data access layer to Firebird (or many other databases) which makes it really easy to manipulate data in C# code
2. Docentric Toolkit is a toolkit for merging MS Word templates with data to create final reports in docx, pdf or xps format. You design template in MS Word and merge it with data in C# application. It can run on a server as well and no MS Office needs to be installed on that server.

I am using those two products very effectively.